# ViewPager in ScrollView does not draw ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

My Layout looks sth like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/newsTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newsHeaderKenburn"
        android:background="@drawable/background_news_tab"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/transparent"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/newsPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newsTabs" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the Layout gets inflated it does not draw the Fragments of the Viewpager. I think its because ScrollView does not know when its layouted which size to expect, because the ViewPager has a flexible size depending on the fragments.
Is there a way to resize the Scrollview after the fragments are layouted ?

Comment: Instead of making the parent layout a `ScrollView`, why don't you make the layout for the `ViewPager` `Fragment`s scrollable? That way, each `Fragment` within the `ViewPager` can scroll.

Comment: i wan't the wholse view scrollable. Also the viepager part of the screen would be pretty small otherwise. I consider though giving the viewpager a fixed height and put the fragments too in a scrollview, need to check out if it works well with the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: @JustinPollard each pager within the scrollview will scroll below tablayout i m using design tablayout +viewpager  so i want once i scroll my viewpager will scroll with its tab means tab will also scroll how will i do ?